# Using multiple thread to write on different sheets of workbook in python

Tags: python, multithreading, excel

```
wb = xlrd.open_workbook('New.xlsx')
wb1 = xlsxwriter.Workbook('Old.xlsx')
def thread_1():
    print('Startind thread 1')
    s1=wb.sheet_by_index(0)
    sh1=wb1.add_worksheet('Base')
    for i in range(17815):
        sh1.write(i,0,s1.cell(i,0).value)
    for i in range(80):
        sh1.write(0,i,s1.cell(0,i).value)
    print('Ending thread 1')
t1=threading.Thread(name='t1',target=thread_1)
t1.start()
def thread_2():
    print('Startind thread 2')
    s2=wb.sheet_by_index(1)
    sh2=wb1.add_worksheet('Her2')
    for i in range(17815):
        sh2.write(i,0,s2.cell(i,0).value)
    for i in range(57):
        sh2.write(0,i,s2.cell(0,i).value)
    print('Ending thread 2')
t2=threading.Thread(name='t2',target=thread_2)
t2.start()
#similarly for rest of the sheets
t1.join()
t2.join()
wb1.close()
```

I wanted to copy my data from one workbook to another workbook (copying only first column and first row)
Here is what I did. I wanted to ask whether its possible to write on same worksheet using different threads. Because above mentioned code is generating 'New.xlsx' file but incorrect.

Comment: If I run threads one at a time then file generated is correct.

Comment: I would guess that you excel library is not thread save.

Comment: What does incorrect mean? How does the excel file look like?

Comment: Excel file obtained should have values filled in first row and first column but the file obtained have only first column filled containing some values from first row and some from first column..